# How long should the loading screen last when installing?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I have a disk for Ubuntu 14.04. When I boot the computer from it I am presented with the GRUB, from where I select "Install Ubuntu." It then hits the loading screen, with the five dots, and appears to hang. I left it for an hour and it did nothing else.

How long is the screen supposed to stay like this? What is it doing?

Also: I ran the "check disk for defects". It tells me an error was found in one file, but doesn't tell me which file, and tells me to press any key to reboot, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> I ran the "check disk for defects". It tells me an error was found in one file

That's enough to say that your live disc is **broken**. Do not use it (may I suggest to trash it?). Try to burn a new DVD or create a USB bootable drive.

If you choose to use a DVD, I suggest performing again a check disk before starting the Ubuntu setup. If no problems are found, you can proceed with the setup. If you find again some problems, you can probably have some hw/sw issues with your DVD drive.